# How to select image from gallery or camera in android?

Tags: gallery, android-camera-intent

I want to know how to select image from camera or gallery programmatically, where image is picked by user in android?

Comment: Mention the problem you are facing while implementing your code...Don't just ask for code.If you are new to android and want some help regarding where to search the same check this out...http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Comment: You just show your code where you get the problem. And if you are newbie to android then for your question @Mandy8055 answer is correct. This is best link http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

Comment: Check the above link for my issue and it works for me @Nikhil Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which image library is suitable for retrieving image from server?.. @Nikhil

Comment: There are many libraries which are available to image from server like Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader etc. @KhusbooGhaghada

Comment: What is the difference between all these Libraries? @Nikhil

Comment: 1.) Picasso has the nicest image API if you are using network.                                                                             2.) UrlImageViewHelper + AndroidAsync is the fastest. Playing with these other two great libraries have really highlighted that the image API is quite dated, however.                                                                                            3.)Android-Universal-Image-Loader is the most popular one out there
currently. Highly customizable.                         4.) Glide is same as Picasso. I prefer Picasso and Glide in my usage. @Khusboo

Comment: Let me also check Picasso lib in my code. @Nikhil

Comment: Excuse me @Nikhil How much memory does picasso use for caching in memory?

Comment: Picasso doesn't add size or occupies more space to your code. It only uses the memory. It is completely transparent, and don't worry about it. Mostly, apps uses Picasso and it works fine at all. @Khusboo

Comment: You are true about Picasso, it works fine @Nikhil

Comment: Absolutely, it works fine. It works great in my app too. @Khusboo

Comment: Your guidance works for me. @Nikhil

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of knowledge, grab it from everywhere. @Khusboo

Comment: Absolutely right. @Nikhil

Comment: Have a happy coding. @Khusboo

Comment: It's fun to get knowledge from right here. @Nikhil

Comment: There are also other accounts available. Try also others for same. @Khusboo

Comment: Yes, I have a look over other accounts too.@Nikhil

Comment: Explore them. @Khusboo

Answer (score -3):

If you are simply using an Android phone or a tablet just get into the gallery long press on the desired photo you need and voila!!! Your picture is selected!!

Comment: @Khusboo asked about the code.